# How can I manage geoserver requests and my page requests in web.xml file?

Tags: geoserver, java

I'm developing an GIS application. I need **wfs** and **wms** protocol in my application. I want to use `Web Feature Module`, `Web Map Module` and `Geoserver Web Modules` of Geoserver's modules. For using these module, I have to add `Platform Core Module`, `OWS Module` and `Main Module` of geoserver's modules.

I create a maven project with netbeans. The dependencies of my project is as following:

```
<dependencies>
<!-- GeoServer Web Application Dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-web-core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-web-wms</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-web-wfs</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-web-sec-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-web-sec-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-platform</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-main</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-wfs</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-wms</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-sec-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-sec-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-wfs-ng</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-arcgrid</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-imagemosaic</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-naming</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-main</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mockrunner</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockrunner</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- End -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai_codec</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai_imageio</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

(I copied these dependencies from pom file of `Geoserver Web Application` module.)

Now `Web.xml` I use two dispatcher as following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>itsme</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>itsme</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/itsme/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm using `itsme` dispatcher for my pages and `dispathcher` dispatcher for geoserver pages. When I delete `dispatcher` dispatcher, I can see my pages, but when I add it, I can't see my pages.

How can I do for this problem?